# ¿Cómo limpiar un TextBox automáticamente en Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, .net, visual-studio

Buenas a todos, tengo una duda bastante simple en Visual Basic .net. Este es mi formulario

[image: dda]

En el TextBox1.Text leo un código de barra que se carga al Label1.Text al cambiar.
Hasta ahí todo bien

[image: dda2]

El problema surge ahora, que quiero leer otro código de barra pero éste se suma al leído anteriormente

[image: dda3]

**Ejemplo**: Tengo 3 productos:

[image: tabla]

Al escanear las galletas, tendré el código 123 en el Textbox1. Pero si luego decido escanear el Maní, tendré 123553 debido a que ambos se juntarán.

He podido hacerlo con un botón, limpiando el campo, pero me gustaría intentar hacerlo automáticamente.

Me gustaría saber cómo limpiar el anterior y dejar el nuevo código cada vez que se lea.
Agradezco sus guías.

Comment: ¿Cómo seteas TextBox1.Text? Lo seteas así?:
TextBox1.Text = ObtenerCodigoSensor();

Comment: @Marlonchosky dentro de TextBox1_TextChanged establezco que el Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text

Comment: Ok pero ese código es como seteas Label1.Text.
Mi pregunta es como seteas TextBox1.Text?
Si lo seteas así:
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    textBox1.Text = guid;
no debería concatenarse las cadenas

Comment: @GeorgeHermsilla Debes añadir el código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola @Marc, es que basicamente no tengo codigo.. solo es en el Textbox1 defini que lo que se escriba pase al Label1, nada mas

Comment: @GeorgeHermsilla creo que no entendí bien tu pregunta. Aclarame esta duda. Lees el valor del sensor desde otro lado y lo tienes en tu portapapeles del sistema, luego vas a la caja de texto y pegas el texto en la  cajita de texto. Este es tu caso?

Comment: Hola @GeorgeHermsilla, por lo general los códigos vienen con una longitud fija, entonces lee la cantidad de caracteres y cuando llegue a esa cierta cantidad limpias el campo. Luego vuelves a escribir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos, George.

Según entiendo, escribes un código leído por el escáner de código de barras en el `TextBox1` y ajustas ese código una vez que ha finalizado al `Label1`. Luego, tu problema comienza cuando escribes **otro** código, ya que éste se agregará al final del código anterior, provocando lo que mostraste en las imágenes.

Básicamente sólo debes eliminar el código anterior, y luego añadir el nuevo código. Para esto puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Crea una variable `booleana` que almacena el estado del `TextBox1`, es decir, si el `TextBox1` tiene o no un código.
- Utiliza el evento `KeyPress` del `TextBox1` para detectar cuando el escáner ha dejado de ingresar los datos.
- Utiliza el evento `KeyDown` para detectar cuando el escáner digitará el primer dato.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim hasCode As Boolean

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If (e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return)) Then
            Label1.Text = "Código: " & TextBox1.Text
            hasCode = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If hasCode Then
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            hasCode = False
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Te explico un poco la lógica:

Cuando inicias tu aplicación, la variable `hasCode` estará `False`, y al momento de ingresar un nuevo código en el `TextBox1` comprobará si ya tiene un código ingresado o no.

En caso de que ya tenga un código escrito (`hasCode = True`), borrará el texto que tenga el `TextBox1` y escribirá los caracteres hasta finalizar.

Cuando finaliza de ingresar el código, generalmente los escáneres escriben un caracter de `return` al final, esto lo comprueba el `KeyPress`.

Al momento de detectar este último caracter, ajusta el texto al `Label1` y ajusta el estado de `hasCode` a `True` (indicando que el `TextBox1` tiene un código ingresado).

Finalmente, repite todo el proceso, si quieres ingresar otro dato. Además, si quieres ingresar un código manualmente, bastará con presionar la tecla `enter` o `intro` para 'validarlo'.

[image: gif]